# Trying use a Backbone.sync for get data from action controller in Rails - non-restful

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm really complicated trying get data from Rails controller through my custom @sync

This is my action controller:

```
class CargasController < ApplicationController
  def readExcel
    @data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @data }
    end  
  end 
end
```

My Backbone model

```
class App.Models.Ruta extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/rutas/'
  readExcel:(opts) ->
    url = 'rutas/readExcel'
    options =
      url: url
      type: 'GET'

    _.extend options, opts

    return (@sync or Backbone.sync).call this, null, this, options
```

And this is my view. (After execute click event I call to readExcel method

```
class App.Views.ShowRuta extends Backbone.View
  events:
    'click button': 'readExcel'

  clasName: 'information'

  template: JST['app/templates/excel_step_one']

  initialize: ->
    @modelo = @model.toJSON()
    @render()

  render: ->
    this.$el.html( @template(@model.toJSON() ) )
    this

  readExcel: ->

    $('h2').html(" Cargando ruta - Espere")

    modelo = @modelo
    $('.contenedor').fadeOut '10000', ->

      $('.col-md-7 h1').html('')
      $('.col-md-7 h4').html('')
      $('.jumbotron').html('')
      $('.contenedor').fadeIn '10000'
      modelo = new App.Models.Ruta({id: modelo.id })

      datos = modelo.readExcel()

      $('.jumbotron').html(datos.readyState)

      console.log datos
      #debugger
```

when I excute "console.log datos." get "resolved"

but when I add to debugger; in the last line dato get a "pending" state

How can I pass from "pending" to "resolved" ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just discover a response for mine.

A example for backbone model

```
class App.Models.Direction extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/directions/'

  defaults:
    id: 1
    address: 'default address'
    latitude: 'default latitude'
    longitude: 'default longitude'
    priority: 'default priority'


  sync: (method, model, opts) ->
    url: 'directions/custom'

    options =
      url: 'directions/custom'
      type: 'GET'

    Backbone.sync.call this, null, this, _.extend(options
    , opts)
```

Then, It's is my controller (For this case for directions_controller.rb

```
class DirectionsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with(@directions = Direction.all)
  end

  def custom
    #You can add a query Rails

    @response = {id: 100, address: 'Direcction', latitude: 199, longitude: 199}
    respond_with(@response)
  end

end
```

In the Rails route.rb you can add this.

```
  resources :directions do
    collection do 
      get :custom
    end
  end
```

Now when you call through the backbone (for example by some backbone view)

```
this.model = new App.Models.Direction
this.model.sync()
this.model.fetch()
```

## Now you model get a rails controller value :)

I hope that solution resolved the problem for any person you've got the same one. I was looking for the solution all weekend.